# How does newtype help hiding anything?

Tags: haskell

Real world haskell says:

> we will hide the details of our parser type using a newtype
>   declaration

I don't get how we can hide anything using the newtype. Can anyone elaborate? What are we trying to hide and how do we do it.

```
data ParseState = ParseState {
  string :: L.ByteString
, offset :: Int64           -- imported from Data.Int
} deriving (Show)


newtype Parse a = Parse {
    runParse :: ParseState -> Either String (a, ParseState)
}
```

Answer (score 12):

The idea is to combine modules + newtypes to keep people from seeing the internals of how we implement things.

```
-- module A
module A (A, toA) where -- Notice we limit our exports
newtype A = A {unA :: Int}

toA :: Int -> A
toA = -- Do clever validation

-- module B
import A
foo :: A
foo = toA 1 -- Must use toA and can't see internals of A
```

This prevents from pattern matching and arbitrarily constructing `A`. This let's our `A` module make certain assumptions about `A` and also change the internals of `A` with impunity!

This is particularly nice because at runtime the `newtype`s are erased so there's almost no overhead from doing something like this

Comment: I would add that this also allows a library developer to _change_ the internals of a type without affecting users of it.  The point of hiding your type isn't just to keep users from performing illegal operations, it also keeps the developer from breaking backwards compatibility in order to add new features.

Comment: Can you do the same trick with `data`? Can you give an example of A with exposed internals.

Comment: Can I expose only certain data constructors or fields of a type?

Comment: @AlekseyBykov `data` also works. To only export certain data constructors or field names, list them in the export list in parentheses after the data/newtype name, e.g. `module A(A(A), toA)`

Comment: Why is newtype so special then?

Comment: @AlekseyBykov, `newtype` is just a wrapper which is meaningful only to the type system. It is not present at runtime, and it does not impose any runtime overhead, contrary to `data`.

Comment: There is also a subtler distinction between them which is that if you open up the constructor of a `data` type then there is a chance you might get bottom (such as an infinite loop), but when you open up a `newtype` type then you are guaranteed to never get bottom.

Comment: @bheklilr That's already in there, see second to last sentence

Comment: @GregoryCrosswhite Can you explain? `newtype Foo = Foo Int; a = Foo undefined`

Comment: @jozefg If we let `a = Foo undefined`, then `case a of Foo _ -> ()` will return `()` if `Foo` was defined using `newtype` and bottom if it was defined using `data`.

Comment: @GregoryCrosswhite Um actually, it doesn't. At least not for me. Data types aren't necessarily strict in their fields

Comment: @jozefg GregoryCrosswhite had the right idea, but slightly wrong execution. Compare `case undefined of Foo _ -> ()` when `Foo` is the constructor of a `data` type and of a `newtype` type.

Comment: @DanielWagner Ah I see

Answer (score 6):

You hide details by not exporting stuff. So there's two comparisons to make. One is exported vs. not exported:

```
-- hidden: nothing you can do with "Parse a" values -- though
-- you can name their type
module Foo (Parse) where
newtype Parse a = Parse { superSecret :: a }

-- not hidden: outsiders can observe that a "Parse a" contains
-- exactly an "a", so they can do anything with a "Parse a" that
-- they can do with an "a"
module Foo (Parse(..)) where
newtype Parse a = Parse { superSecret :: a }
```

The other is more subtle, and is the one RWH is probably trying to highlight, and that is `type` vs. `newtype`:

```
-- hidden, as before
module Foo (Parse) where
newtype Parse a = Parse { superSecret :: a }

-- not hidden: it is readily observable that "Parse a" is identical
-- to "a", and moreover it can't be fixed because there's nothing
-- to hide
module Foo (Parse) where
type Parse a = a
```