# How does the function embeded in runParse of RWH get parameter with type ParseState?

Tags: haskell

After reading [LYAH's Chapter 08](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#type-parameters) and SO questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19872175/1054800), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18205862/1054800)) about Real World Haskell's `Parse` definition:

```
newtype Parse a = Parse {
runParse :: ParseState -> Either String (a, ParseState) }
```

For me, now I think it is a key understanding how `runParse` is evaluated when `runParse` is viewed as a function.

(1) `ghci> :t runParse` will get

```
runParse :: Parse a -> ParseState -> Either String (a, ParseState)
```

(2) For trying `runParse`, similar to RWH's `The identity Parser` , I used the following example:

```
ghci> runParse (Parse (\s -> Right (1,s))) (ParseState (L8.pack "") 0)
```

I got the result:

```
Right (1,ParseState {string = "", offset = 0})
```

I can guess that the above evaluation is that `(Parse (\s -> Right (1,s)))` and `(ParseState (L8.pack "") 0)` first are parameters of `runParse` and anonymous function `(\s -> Right (1, s))`   uses `(ParseState (L8.pack "") 0)` as its parameter . But this guess makes me confused:

Why `(ParseState (L8.pack "") 0)` is used as `(\s -> Right (1, s))` 's parameter during evaluating? How does the whole `runParse` eval finish?

Also, I can write an alternative function for a simple definition, such as in LYAH:

```
newtype CharList = CharList {getCharList :: [Char]}
```

For this, `CharList` and `getCharList` can be defined as:

```
newtype CharList = CharList [Char]

getCharList :: CharList -> [Char]
getCharList cl = case cl of
    CharList x -> x
```

So, in the first definition for `CharList`, it is sure that there exists a pattern match. If I can implement a explicit function with pattern match like this for the previous `runParse` I will understand it. But I don't know how to do it?

Comment: `runParse` simple retrieves a value from a record. `runParse (Parse (\s -> Right (1,s)))` is exactly equal to `\s -> Right (1,s)`. After that, it is just regular function application.

Comment: @user2407038 thanks! Why these exists such a equation relations? where I can get a relative reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours, I think I can answer this myself.

Because `runParse` is a function with two parameters:

```
runParse :: Parse a -> ParseState -> Either String (a, ParseState)
```

After reviewing `Partial Function Application principal` RWH descriped : **`In Haskell,  all functions take only one argument.`**   I know that

```
ghci> runParse (Parse (\s -> Right (1,s))) (ParseState (L8.pack "") 0)
```

and :

```
ghci> let y = runParse (Parse (\s -> Right (1,s)))
ghci> y (ParseState (L8.pack "") 0)
```

are the same, and in `ghci` this evaluation must be divided into two steps:

(1) evaluating the function `runParse` with a parameter `Parse a`, which returns a function with a parameter with type `ParseState`, if `Parse a` is `(Parse (\s -> Right (1,s)))` , according to the simplest example in LYAH:

```
ghci> newtype CharList = CharList {getCharList :: [Char]}
ghci> getCharList (CharList "ab")
"ab"
```

so the result of executing

`runParse (Parse (\s -> Right (1,s)))` is `(\s -> Right (1,s))`, and it is verified from the fact: the type of `ghci> :t runParse (Parse (\s -> Right (1,s)))` is

```
runParse (Parse (\s -> Right (1,s))) :: Num a => ParseState -> Either String (a, ParseState)
```

(2) after difficult step (1) for me,  I get a function called `y` in this case, which needs a parameter with a type `ParseState`, `y (ParseState (L8.pack "") 0)` will get a predicated result:
`Right (1,ParseState {string = "", offset = 0})`

I need keep it in mind that , for a function with more than one parameters, either you give all parameters one time or you give one parameter one time, the function's evaluation flow always includes the same amount as the number of parameters of steps and every step evaluates a function with one parameter.

Comment: A few thoughts: `runParse` is defined just as you thought: `runParse (Parse f) = f` so `runParser (Parse p) a = p a` which means in you example the entire thing ends in `Right (1, ... the state ...)` which is indeed what we see