# StackOverflow comment's html anchor such as "http://SO/...#comment41994753_26699358"

Tags: javascript, html, stackexchange

I found SO's comment can be anchored and difficult for me to understand the implement. The following link is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26696064/how-does-the-function-embeded-in-runparse-of-rwh-get-parameter-with-type-parsest/26699358?noredirect=1#comment41994753_26699358) anchoring a comment:

```
http://SO/questions/26696064/slug/26699358?noredirect=1#comment41994753_26699358
```

From my understanding about html, `comment41994753_26699358` after `#` must be existed in the html page, but I did not find the `id` or `name` in it. When I read the source code I only find the relative source code:

```
<div id="comments-26699358" class="comments ">
        <table>
            <tbody data-remaining-comments-count="0" data-canpost="true" data-cansee="false" data-comments-unavailable="false" data-addlink-disabled="false">
               <tr id="comment-41994753" class="comment ">
```

This snippet only tells me two relative and separated ids `id="comment-41994753"` and `id="comments-26699358"`, the final anchor `comment41994753_26699358` is generated from them? Or this is relative to the framework SO used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's no browser behavior, the orange background color and its scroll into view happens with JavaScript.

The code is in this file: http://cdn.sstatic.net/Js/full.en.js
The non-minified version: http://dev.stackoverflow.com/content/js/full.js

The important functions are `onHashChange_HighlightDestination` and `doHighlight`:

`onHashChange_HighlightDestination`:
It parses the hash argument, e. g. `#comment49509148_30726127` and calls the highlight method afterwards.

```
// answers have the form 'lies-like/58534#58534'; comments are 'lies-like/58534#comment60949_58534'
var match = decodeURI(url).match(/#(\d+|comment(\d+)_(\d+))/i);
if (!match) return; // moderator viewing a flagged question, e.g. 'lies-like#question'

if (match[2])
    highlightComment(match[2], match[3]);
else
    highlightAnswer(match[1]);
```

`doHighlight`: This method finally highlights it (orange background) and scrolls the comment/answer into view with the function [`scrollIntoView`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView).

```
var doHighlight = function (jEle) {
    var originalColor = backgroundColor;
    jEle
        .css({ backgroundColor: highlightColor })
        .animate({ backgroundColor: originalColor }, 2000, 'linear', function () { $(this).css('background-color', ''); });

    if (jEle.is('.comment'))
        jEle[0].scrollIntoView(true);
};
```

Comment: I am so sorry, maybe, my question is not clear? I don't care about the colour,  I care that how SO can anchor the comment with `#comment41994753_26699358`,  or say,  navigate the comment? I understand the simplest anchor link example : `<a href="#anyword">Jump to any place</a> ` and `<a name="anyword">Jump to this place</a>`

Comment: @@Andy, `scrollIntoView` make the specific comment scroll to the top-most part of the page?

Comment: @abelard2008 Exactly, I just edited my answer to clarify this.

Answer (score 2):

The answer lies in the `onHashChange_HighlightDestination` function in the javascript code, which is called from the `init` method, which fires on every request.

As you can see in the [developer edition of the javascript code](http://dev.stackoverflow.com/content/js/full.js), it tries to extract the post id and comment id from the request hash:

```
var match = decodeURI(url).match(/#(\d+|comment(\d+)_(\d+))/i);
```

From there it calls `highlightComment`, which does the `scrollIntoView` and CSS highlighting.

Comment: @@Patrick, when user press enter key in the url address, `onHashChange_HighlightDestination ` will be called, and then `highlightComment `, I am right?

Comment: No, it just calls it when a page is loaded.